# Git push not working when done remotely over ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I have a private repository on GitLab and I am trying to do git push and pull remotely.

```
git push origin master
```

works as expected when executed locally. However, if I connect to the PC over ssh and then try to do `git push origin master` in the `ssh` session, I get a following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have a working ssh key for the repository on both devices, I can do `git push` from both of them locally. However, when I connect one to the other through ssh, it no longer works. I have found a lot of related questions but none contains my specific issue. Do you have any idea how to make remote push work?

Comment: Do you login over ssh as the same user as you login locally (i.e. if the ssh key is accessible)? Do you use `ssh-agent` and do you use agent forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare what git push does when done locally on the remote PC, or done through an SSH session on the remote PC with:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
git push

# or (Windows)
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
git push
```

You will see if the exact same `id_rsa.pub` public key is selected or not.